# repl is not working(clojure box)

Tags: emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, slime

I want to use syntax highlighting for clojure in emacs + slime + clojure.

So I did following step.

1. run clojure box
2. M-x clojure-mode in *slime-repl clojure*
3. syntax highlighting is success.

But repl is not working. I expect a result of 3. But cursor blinks.
repl no response.

```
; SLIME 
user> (+ 1 2)

-K\**_   *slime-repl clojure*   All L6     (Clojure Slime[clojure])----------
```

REPL suspected feature is turned off.

Thanks in advance.

BR
ChangMin Jeon

Answer (score 3):

Here's [a Gist](http://gist.github.com/337280) with my coloured REPL setup for Clojure (prepared a while ago in response to an SO question... I'm really grateful for the prod to the person who asked that one!). Notice how it uses `defadvice` to alter the behaviour of SLIME's REPL, rather than changing the major mode in the REPL buffer.